# How to parse a milliseconds-since-epoch timestamp string in Go?

Tags: string, datetime, go

I've got a string with milliseconds since the epoch (it came originally from a `java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()` call).  What's the right way to convert this string into a human readable timestamp string in Go?

Looking at [the time package](http://golang.org/pkg/time/) I see the `Parse` function, but the layouts all seem to be normal timezone-based times.  Once into a Time object, I can use [`Format(Time.Stamp)`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) to get the output I want, but I'm not clear on how to get the string into a Time object.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The format string does not support milliseconds since the epoch, so you need to parse manually. For example:

```
func msToTime(ms string) (time.Time, error) {
    msInt, err := strconv.ParseInt(ms, 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return time.Time{}, err
    }

    return time.Unix(0, msInt*int64(time.Millisecond)), nil
}
```

Check out http://play.golang.org/p/M1dWGLT8XE to play with the example live.

Comment: Your solution works, but it's taking advantage of `time.Unix` accommodating nanosecond values of range. You're converting milliseconds to nanoseconds, but ignoring that you should really convert milliseconds to seconds and remaining nanoseconds. Here's an adaptation of your solution: http://play.golang.org/p/XKHNPkSqgx.

Comment: Why do more work that is harder to read and you could get wrong when the stdlib has done it for you?

From the docs: `It is valid to pass nsec outside the range [0, 999999999].` https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Unix

Comment: @StephenWeinberg Because `2**63-1` nanoseconds is only 292.3 years. So if, for any reason, you expect to ever have to deal with dates before 1677 or after 2262, you should convert to seconds + nanoseconds rather than only nanoseconds. Of course, OP says his value is from Java `currentTimeMillis`, so unless his software is still going to be used in 300 years...; yeah that's probably unlikely. Still worth being aware of though, I think.

Comment: when I use this with a full epoch time I get.
```0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC strconv.ParseInt: parsing "1352397861001.9878789": invalid syntax```
which means I need to remove the nanoseconds.

Comment: The invalid syntax is from ParseInt which assumes an integer. If you can convert the input into number of nanosecond since epoch, you can use it in the time.Unix function (replacing `msInt*int64(time.Millisecond)`).

Answer (score 5):

2021 update: you can use [`UnixMilli`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#UnixMilli) to parse from the integer. This would improve the accepted answer to:

```golang
 func msToTime(ms string) (time.Time, error) {
    msInt, err := strconv.ParseInt(ms, 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return time.Time{}, err
    }

    return time.UnixMilli(msInt), nil
}
```

Comment: This is available starting from Go 1.17

Answer (score 3):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13295158) will not work for some date ranges either too far in the future or too far in the past because only a limited date range can be described using 64 bits (plus or minus 300 years from Epoch).

This will work for the entire range describable by milliseconds:

```golang
var Epoch = time.Unix(0, 0)

func ParseMillisecondUnixTimestamp(s string) (time.Time, error) {
    ts, err := strconv.Atoi(s)
    if err != nil {
        return time.Time{}, err
    }

    return Epoch.Add(time.Duration(ts) * time.Millisecond), nil
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `time.Unix(ms/1000, 0)` would do the trick.

First convert the ms-timestamp to unix-timestamp using the well known relation `1 s = 1000 ms` and then use the result as first argument to the `time.Unix` function

Comment: I just tested this approach and you end up losing precision this way.

https://play.golang.org/p/XWpS-PtRJrj

Output:
Time [2020-09-30 00:31:29.461 +0000 UTC], Time2 [2020-09-30 00:31:29 +0000 UTC]